# Authenticated user is set to null after page refresh in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm coding a real estate app in react with postgres & node js.

At the moment I'm having some struggles with my useAuthContext.
When I login, I can see my name being displayed in the navbar as a welcome sign. When I refresh the page, I'm still logged in.
When I go to my profile dashboard, I can see my data, but when I refresh the page, I get errors because my authenticated user is set to null.. .

I have no clue where the exact issue is but reaching out to other programmers wasn't helpful so maybe some of you guys can see the problem.

Here is a [video](https://www.loom.com/share/c404bbedce2e48f18987019343e3c8ab) of me explaining the problem.

My useAuthContext:

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import axios from '../config/axios';

const initialState = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    user: null,
};

const authReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "LOGIN":
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                user: action.data.user,
            };
        case "LOGOUT":
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: false,
                user: null,
            };
    }
};

const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, initialState);

    const fetchUserInfo = async () => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

        if (token) {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get("api/user/me", {
                    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
                });

                axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = token;

                dispatch({
                    type: "LOGIN",
                    data: {
                        user: response.data.user,
                    },
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                // TODO handle expired JWT token response
            }
        } else {
            delete axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"];
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const verifyUser = async () => {
            if (!state.user) {
                await fetchUserInfo();
            }
        };
        verifyUser();
    }, []);

    const register = async (registerData) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post("api/auth/register", registerData);
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            if (!error.response) {
                return { status: "ERRROR", message: "No Server Response" };
            } else if (error.response.status === 409) {
                return error.response.data;
            } else if (error.response.status === 400) {
                return error.response.data;
            } else {
                return error.response.data;
            }
        }
    };

    const login = async (loginData) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post("api/auth/login", loginData);
            localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
            await fetchUserInfo();
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            if (!error.response) {
                return { type: "ERROR", message: "No Server Response" };
            } else if (error.response.status === 400) {
                return error.response.data;
            } else if (error.response.status === 401) {
                return error.response.data;
            } else {
                return error.response.data;
            }
        }
    };

    const logout = async () => {
        try {
            localStorage.removeItem("token");
            dispatch({
                type: "LOGOUT",
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.response);
        }
    };

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch, register, login, logout }}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

export default AuthContext;
```

The dashboard:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import useAuthContext from '../../../hooks/useAuthContext';
import InputField from '../InputField';
import Button from '../Button';
import './user.css';

const UserDashboard = () => {

    const { state } = useAuthContext() 

    console.log(state)

    const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
        nameUser: state.user.username,
        mail: state.user.email,
    })

    const handleChange = async (e) => {
        setUserData({
            ...userData,
            [e.currentTarget.name]: e.currentTarget.value
        })
    }

    return (
        <div className='user-form'>
            <h1 className='page-title'>User Dashboard</h1>
            <div className='profile-picture-container'>
                <div className='profile-picture'>
                    <img />
                </div>
                <button>Change profile-picture</button>
            </div>
            <InputField placeholder="Full name" className="form-input" name="username" type="text" value={userData.nameUser} onChange={handleChange} />
            <InputField placeholder="Email" className="form-input" name="email" type="text" value={userData.mail} onChange={handleChange} />
            <Button type="submit" input="UPDATE USER INFO" className={`form-button`} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default UserDashboard;
```

useAuthContext hook:

```
import AuthContext from "../context/AuthContext";
import { useContext } from "react";

const useAuthContext = () => {
    const context = useContext(AuthContext)

    if (!context) {
        throw Error('useAuthContext must be used inside an AuthContextProvider')
    }

    return context
}

export default useAuthContext;
```

If there is any other code needed, let me know